# PHP - gmdate() and Large Integers

Tags: php

I'm getting a result I'm not expecting from `gmdate()`

```
<?php
$secs = 175707;
echo gmdate("H:i:s", $secs); // result: 00:48:27
?>
```

The result is **00:48:27**, which is way off.  It appears the hours is getting pushed down a position.  Am I suspecting that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gmdate works on dates, not periods of time. In other words, your timestamp is being interpreted as a point in time early in January 3rd of 1970 (specifically 00:00:00 1 Jan 1970 + 15707 seconds = 00:48:27 3 Jan 1970). This is where your 00:48:27 comes from.

---

`gmdate` (and `date`) are not meant to be used this way. If you just want to calculate hours/minutes/seconds based on number of seconds, calculate them directly:

```
$seconds = 175707;
$hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
$seconds -= $hours * 3600;
$minutes = floor($seconds / 60);
$seconds -= $minutes * 60;

echo "$hours:$minutes:$seconds"; //48:48:27
```

---

Make note that this does not work with civil days. This is because of daylight saving time. A day is not always 24 hours. Sometimes it's 23, and sometimes its 25 when DST is coming into effect or ending. With days as a unit of measure (i.e. a day is always 24 hours), this does work. As an example, 10 March is 23 hours and 3 Nov is 25 hours in the United States. If you are happy with static 24 hours days, then the same approach will of course work.

Answer (score 0):

gmdate() expects a UNIX timestamp - seconds since Jan 1/1970. You've passed in the equivalent of `Saturday, Jan 3rd, 1970, 12:48:27am`.

e.g. try this:

```
echo gmdate('r', 175707);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](http://php.net/gmdate)

> the time returned is Greenwich Mean Time (GMT)

So if you're in CET (GMT +1) it indeed will give you an hour of 0.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this if you want to see where you are going wrong:

```
echo date("d-M-Y H:i:s", 175707);
```

That will give an output of `03-Jan-1970 00:48:27`. i.e. [175707 seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) from 00:00:00 on the 1st of January 1970 = `03-Jan-1970 00:48:27`.